# How can I SUM distinct records in a Postgres database where there are duplicate records?

Tags: postgresql

Imagine a table that looks like this:

[image: table with duplicate data]

The SQL to get this data was just SELECT * 
The first column is "row_id" the second is "id" - which is the order ID and the third is "total" - which is the revenue.

I'm not sure why there are duplicate rows in the database, but when I do a SUM(total), it's including the second entry in the database, even though the order ID is the same, which is causing my numbers to be larger than if I select distinct(id), total - export to excel and then sum the values manually.

So my question is - how can I SUM on just the distinct order IDs so that I get the same revenue as if I exported to excel every distinct order ID row?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 27):

Easy - just divide by the count:

```
select id, sum(total) / count(id)
from orders
group by id
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cef1c/1).

Also handles any level of duplication, eg triplicates etc.

Comment: This is so clever!

Comment: This will not return the sum of `total` of all distinct records as required.

Comment: @sparky just to confirm, this is *correct*. Each id is independent of, and totally unrelated to, the frequency of another id. It doesn’t matter how many times an id appears. Since each id has only one distinct value, the total is `n * total` and count is `n`, so dividing gives `total` for all values of `n` (`n` can’t be zero, of course). If you aren’t convinced, post some sample data to support your belief.

Comment: No, the result is the mean average of totals distinct on `id`, not the sum of `total`s distinct on `id`. For the sum, we'd need the division by count of `id`s *inside* the `sum( )`, but aggregates can't be nested.

Comment: @OJFord however, OP’s case is special: All rows for a given id are duplicates, ie they all have the same value for `total`, thus they are all also the average. Try my query with OP’s data and you’ll see it works.

Comment: @OJFord I have added a link to a live demo to prove it :  see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cef1c/1

Comment: That just seems like an over-fit solution - we could also just return literals and prove it works for OP's data.

Comment: @Bohemian This answer is indeed NOT correct. It does not sum distinct records, just like @chumakoff said. Instead it just prints distinct records. You will achieve exactly the same by doing `select distinct id, total from orders`.

Comment: @Googie I’m sure this query *is* correct, and I the linked demo proves that. If after reviewing the demo you still believe it is incorrect, please show an example of data for which this query doesn’t provide the correct result by modifying the linked demo and posting its link here.

Comment: @Bohemian To begin with - as I already mentioned - you will get the same result with simpler query using `distinct` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cef1c/48 , but that's not the point. The point is that the author asked how to get sum of total values but only for distinct ids. This can be achieved in two ways - either this simple one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cef1c/51 or using CTE, which - while more complex - allows for further row-by-row processing (like subsequent selects per row - useful in hierarchical data structures): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cef1c/53

Comment: The CTE solution mentioned in the comment above is especially useful if you join several tables in one-to-many relations and you group results by various columns, apply aggregate functions and suddenly you find out some aggregations do not sum up correctly. CTE allows you to decompose complex aggregations into several steps, thus allowing proper calculations.

Comment: @Googie just to be clear, the question does *not* ask "only for distinct ids", ie only return ids that don't have duplicates, the question asks for duplicated data to be ignored. Maybe you don't like the style, but this query actually works and delivers what OP asked for.

Comment: @Bohemian The question explicitly states *"how can I SUM on just the distinct order IDs"*. Author has posted screenshot of excel just to illustrate problem of duplicates, but he asked for a sum over distinct ids, not list of distinct values.

Comment: This is not working if record has different count of joined rows. For example: (1*10 * 2*20 + 3*30( = 140 / (1 + 2 + 3) = 23,(3), but it should be 10 + 20 + 30 = 60.

Comment: @DmitryKrakosevich This is not meant to work with different values. This question and my answer are about **duplicate values** (all values for the group are *the same*, but there is a variable quantity of them). Your example has *different* values. Please carefully re-read the question.

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this (with your example):

**Table**

```
create table test (
  row_id int,
  id int,
  total decimal(15,2)
);

insert into test values 
(6395, 1509, 112), (22986, 1509, 112), 
(1393, 3284, 40.37), (24360, 3284, 40.37);
```

**Query**

```
with distinct_records as (
  select distinct id, total from test
)

select a.id, b.actual_total, array_agg(a.row_id) as row_ids
from test a
inner join (select id, sum(total) as actual_total from distinct_records group by id) b
  on a.id = b.id
group by a.id, b.actual_total
```

**Result**

```
|   id | actual_total |    row_ids |
|------|--------------|------------|
| 1509 |          112 | 6395,22986 |
| 3284 |        40.37 | 1393,24360 |
```

**Explanation**

We do not know what the reasons is for orders and totals to appear more than one time with different row_id. So using a common table expression (CTE) using the `with ...` phrase, we get the distinct id and total.

Under the CTE, we use this distinct data to do totaling. We join ID in the original table with the aggregation over distinct values. Then we comma-separate row_ids so that the information looks cleaner.

**SQLFiddle example**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/72639/3

Comment: This answer so undervalued, while it's the only one providing correct (and almost complete) solution to the question asked! To complete it it's worth to mention that in the second part of CTE (with actual `select a.id....`) the author should `SELECT sum(b.actual_total)` and skip `group by` entirely. That will give sum of total in all distinct (by id) rows.

Answer (score 5):

Create custom aggregate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_func (
  double precision, pg_catalog.anyelement, double precision
)
RETURNS double precision AS
$body$
SELECT case when $3 is not null then COALESCE($1, 0) + $3 else $1 end
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE AGGREGATE dist_sum (
  pg_catalog."any", 
  double precision)
(
  SFUNC = sum_func,
  STYPE = float8
);
```

And then calc distinct sum like:

```
select dist_sum(distinct id, total)
from orders
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ae9a/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DISTINCT` in your aggregate functions:

```
SELECT id, SUM(DISTINCT total) FROM orders GROUP BY id
```

Documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: I'm not going to delete this, but this is actually *wrong*. When using `distinct` inside of an aggregate function, it gets the distinct values of the column, so if you have any distinct orders with the same total, then your sum is going to be inaccurate. The `sum(total) / count(id)` wins this one.

Comment: The `sum(total) / count(id)` is also wrong. It basically returns arithmetic average of the total column. If you follow @Bohemian answer (that is - to `group by id`) you will get averages per each id - which is also not what the author was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

In difficult cases:

```sql
select
  id,
  (
    SELECT SUM(value::int4)
    FROM jsonb_each_text(jsonb_object_agg(row_id, total))
  ) as total
from orders
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can trust that the total for 1 order is actually 1 row.  We could eliminate the duplicates in a sub-query by selecting the the MAX of the PK id column. An example:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (id int, order_id int, total int);

insert into test2 values (1,1,50);
insert into test2 values (2,1,50);
insert into test2 values (5,1,50);
insert into test2 values (3,2,100);
insert into test2 values (4,2,100);

select order_id, sum(total)
   from test2 t
   join (
     select max(id) as id
      from test2 
       group by order_id) as sq
  on t.id = sq.id
  group by order_id
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/7368)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just use a sub-Query:

```
SELECT "a"."id", SUM("a"."total")
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("id") * FROM "Database"."Schema"."Table") AS "a"
GROUP BY "a"."id"
```

The Above will give you the total of each id

Use below if you want the full total of each duplicate removed:

```
SELECT SUM("a"."total")
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("id") * FROM "Database"."Schema"."Table") AS "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using subselect (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cef1c/51):

```
select sum(total) from (
  select distinct id, total
  from orders
)
```

Using CTE (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cef1c/53):

```
with distinct_records as (
  select distinct id, total from orders
)
select sum(total) from distinct_records;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler and more elegant solution to this problem.

```
select id,
(select sum(value::integer) from jsonb_each(jsonb_object_agg(table.id, table.total)))
from table
```